# Как передать переменную с одной страницы на другую

Tags: javascript

Допустим на первой странице есть input и кнопка

```
HTML
    <input type="number" id="input1">
    <button onclick="go_to();">Далее</button>
```

При нажатии на кнопку число из input записывается в переменную и открывается следующая страница

```
JS
    var num;
    
    function go_to() {
      var num = input1.value;
      window.location.href = 'second.html';
    }
```

Как на следующей странице вывести переменную num?

Answer (score 1):

Сохранить переменную в localStorage, и на следующей странице взять переменную из localStorage при загрузке.

Выглядит это не сложно:

```
function go_to() {
  localStorage.setItem('num', input1.value);
  window.location.href = 'second.html';
}

// на целевой странице
let num = null
if (localStorage.getItem('num')) {
  num = localStorage.getItem('num')
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста не надо вставлять невоспроизводимый код как воспроизводимый. Ваш код не очень корректен. За пределами вашего `if`-а переменную `num` нельзя будет использовать. Лучше сделайте так, чтобы его можно было достать везде, где она будет использоваться

Comment: Большое спасибо, все работает!

Comment: EzioMercer, согласен, не корректный пример написал)

Answer (score 0):

Для передачи значения переменной с одной страницы на другую не обязательно сохранять его в LocalStorage. Достаточно одну строку в функции переписать так:

```
window.location.href = 'second.html?' + num;
```

а на целевой странице принять её таким образом:

```
let num = location.search.substring(1);
console.log(num);
```

Взято от сюда: [Передача и обработка данных в html-файле](https://www.spravkaweb.ru/javascript/sovet/get)